# Adding logback to all my classess

Tags: spring, file, logback

we have a huge project with a huge count of classes, we want to add the logback to all the classes:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

and add the line:

```
private static final Log logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

is there any automatic way to make this refactoring/injection?

Comment: Why not just add it as and when you write log statements? You are going to have to do those manually anyway. All you need to do is copy and paste `private static final Log logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);` into the file and then hit ctrl + shift + o in Eclipse to import the classes (I think thats the shortcut)

Comment: yes it is an exist huge count of classes

Comment: But you only need it in a class when you actually add a log statement to log something. Which you will have to do manually. There is no benefit in adding the log declaration to classes that dont actually log anything.